# Go generics: return slice of underlying type as []T

Tags: go, generics, type-conversion

I am working on a genetic algorithm library, and I use a generic type declaration for the bases of each gene, i.e. `type Gene[T comparable] struct { Bases: []T }`. The reason for this is that not every problem can be solved using a particular data type, e.g. `float64` or `uint8`, so it is designed to be flexible to the end-user use cases. I have run into an issue with the sequencing scheme, where genes are separated by `separator []T`: in the case of an empty final gene, sequencing results in an anomalous separator that should not be there, which can cause desequencing to parse it as a separate allele or a gene containing just the separator. There are two ways to deal with it: the first way is to ignore empty genetic structs and exclude them during sequencing, but this may delete structural information that is useful, e.g. in the case of saving intermediate genomes including genetic drift during a simulation/optimization; the second way is to introduce a placeholder sequence to identify empty structures. The latter is what I wish to do.

I would like for this placeholder sequence to be generated automatically from the separator by flipping the bits of each base in the `separator []T`, and I can use the "reflect" package to detect which type is being used. However, I cannot return `[]int` when the function return signature is `[]T`. I can do something like the following, but I am unsure if it is good practice.

```golang
func inverseSeparator[T comparable](separator []T) []T {
    result := []T
    switch reflect.TypeOf(separator[0]).Kind() {
    case reflect.Int:
        var v interface{}
        for i := 0; i < len(separator); i++ {
            // do the bit flip
            v = resultOfBitFlip 
            result = append(result, v.(T))
        }
    // other cases
    }
    return result
}
```

What is the best way to go about converting the result of the bit flipping back to a slice of `T`, or is this a bad approach?

Comment: you don't need reflect for that.  You can do a type assertion (https://go.dev/tour/methods/16)

Comment: @erik258 interesting idea, but when I try it I get the following error: "cannot use type switch on type parameter value separator[0] (variable of type T constrained by comparable)"

Comment: `cannot use type switch on type parameter value separator[0] (variable of type T constrained by comparable)`. Write it like this: `any(separator[0]).(type)`. In a type assertion `x.(T)`, `x` should be of interface type, but not a type parameter. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions.

Comment: It sounds like want to support numerical types only. If that's true, and assuming zero and/or negative values are not valid base representations, you can change your constraint to [Signed](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Signed) and use those as sentinel values. You can compare to zero without reflection or type assertions with this constraint.

Comment: @ZekeLu that works and removes the reflect dependency. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter actually, I think that I'll support Ordered types + bools rather than comparable since pointers and structs cannot be bit flipped in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

- I think a good optimization for the attached code is the following, it provides a basic **error-handling** mechanism:

```
func inverseSeparator[T comparable](separator []T) ([]T, error) {
    switch separator[0].(type) {
    case int:
        var result []T
        for _, val := range separator {
            // Perform bit flip
            // Make sure T is a valid numeric type (int, uint, etc.) before flipping bits
            if n, ok := val.(int); ok {
                // Perform bit flipping for integers
                flipped := ^n
                result = append(result, T(flipped).(T))
            } else {
                // Return an error if the type is not supported for bit flipping
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported type for bit flipping: %T", val)
            }
        }
        return result, nil
    // Handle other cases for different types, if needed.
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported type for inverseSeparator: %T", separator[0])
    }
}
```